# Unable to insert data into PostgreSql in symfony with complex relation

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two tables `users` and `ticket_status`. Users has id,name etc. Ticket_status has id,createdBy(fk of users),and time.

As I am using doctrine and symfony. So I have to add an instance of `users` class in ticket_status createdBy.

After getting an user using id and setting in setCreatedBy. When I try to persist into database it shows an error.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT NEXTVAL('ticket_status_id_seq')':

SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "ticket_status_id_seq" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT NEXTVAL('ticket_status_id_seq')
```

and If I try to print_r the object it shows `OutOfMemoryException`

I have added my ticket_status entity classes and controller class where I have added the original logic.[TicketStatus.php](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxB5rnTrRuVyNFhlbmgwdWZrWFE)

[TestController.php](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxB5rnTrRuVyVUxWYjJvSGVfVjA)

Comment: Did you create the tables using doctrine? What's the primary key of ticket_status and what type is it? It seems that doctrine is looking for a sequence that has not been defined

Comment: I have already added the file. You can see it. id is the pkey. And firstly I created the tables then I generated the entity files using doctrine.

Comment: Try executing `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update` and post results

Answer (score 1):

You have not table in **`Database`;**

1) You have to `run command update schema`:

a. `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` // show your status database if have some changes shows

b. `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

2) If you use Symfony2 run command with `php app/console ...`